# Event Receiver for custom List and Document Library

Tags: document-library, custom-list, event-receivers

What is the difference between Event Receivers for custom lists and a document libraries?

The Document library Events are firing even when we select a custom list event receiver.

What exactly is the difference between these two?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no difference. Type of list defines the destination content type in elements.xml in event reciever feature

Comment: then why a seperate event receiver for document libraries??

Comment: It just makes generation of elements.xml easier: "<Receivers ListTemplateId="100">" for Custom List and "<Receivers ListTemplateId="101">" for Document Library.

Comment: But number of events available for document libraries will be more right?

Comment: No, available events are the same.

Comment: What about check in , check out events?

Comment: Yes, Сheck-in/Check-out is only available for document libraries. But you stil can register item checked event for custom list.